# How can I optimize string replacement in Swift with base64 file in it?

Tags: ios, swift, optimization

I have a problem regarding String replacements in Swift. The web-server communicates via XML, the files are encoded in base64 and sent over XML. I have a few helper functions which gets an XML template, replace some headers, and then replace #data# with base64 encoded binary data (image, document).

Same operation on Android is almost instant. On iOS for some reason, it takes much longer. It takes about 1.6 seconds to return the final XML at 100 % CPU usage. Real time is like 4 seconds. It runs on background thread also...

```
 local = insertHeaders(xml: local)
 local = local.replace(this: "#type#", with: "saveoperation")
 local = local.replace(this: "#id#", with: id)
 local = local.replace(this: "#data#", with: xmlData.getEncryptedString)
```

The String.replace function is take from here:

```
func replace(this pattern : String, with newValue: String) -> String {
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.count)
        let modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: newValue)
        return modString
}
```

There is any efficient way to replace text in a string ?

Comment: You're also doing a lot of passes through the string. Each `replace` call is equivalent to `for`-looping through the entire string. Also note that you don't memoize your `regex` local variable, so you're re-compiling the regular expression 3 times per file.

Comment: These `#type#` placeholders are really fishy. This system will break the moment your XML has a need to actually express the text `#type#`, which is unlikely, but still a risk going forward which can easily be replaced. Why don't you just construct this XML with the `"saveoperation"`, `id` and encrypted string, from initial construction? Then you don't have to waste time going back to find the placeholders to replace them.

Comment: Like how ? let string  = "<xml>" + variable + "</xml>" ?

Comment: Fundamentally, yes, but I would use an XML builder to do that for me, to abstract away the finnicky details of open/close tags, new lines, indentation, inserting CDATA sections, etc. Something like https://github.com/MaxDesiatov/XMLCoder Using an encoder that leverages the Codable system also lets you be data-format independant. In a few lines of code, you could switch all your communication to JSON, YAML, or whatever the future might hold.

Answer (score 0):

Just use String.replacingOccurrences(). I reduced the time from 1.6 seconds to 0.4 seconds !

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
replacingOccurrences(of: "", with: "")
```

For Example:

let myString = "Hello World" now using replacingOccurrences(of: "", with: "") i can replace whitespace by -

```
let result = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "-")
```

then the result will be:

```
Hello-World
```

and you can use the same method to change a particular words